# PHP / List of the hours between values

Tags: php

I have 2 variables

```
$a = '09:00'
$b = '13:00'
```

Tell me how to get a list:

> 9:00
>   10:00
>   11:00
>   12:00

without end `13:00`

thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [`DatePeriod`](http://php.net/dateperiod) class to easily loop between the two times with, in this case, an interval of 1 hour.

```
<?php

$a = '09:00';
$b = '13:00';

$period = new DatePeriod(
    new DateTime($a),
    new DateInterval('PT1H'),
    new DateTime($b)
);
foreach ($period as $date) {
    echo $date->format("H:i\n");
}

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would do it with a `for` loop :)

```
$a = '09:00';
$b = '13:00';

// convert the strings to unix timestamps
$a = strtotime($a);
$b = strtotime($b);

// loop over every hour (3600sec) between the two timestamps
for($i = 0; $i < $b - $a; $i += 3600) {
  // add the current iteration and echo it
  echo date('H:i', $a + $i).'<br>';
}
```

Output:

```
09:00
10:00
11:00
12:00
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$a = '09:00';
$b = '13:00';
$s = strtotime($a);
$e = strtotime($b);

while($s < $e) {
   echo date ("h:i", $s) . "\n";
   $s = strtotime (date ("h:i", $s) . " +1 hour");
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution using \DateTime is:

```
$a = '09:00';
$b = '13:00';

$dtStart = \DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i',$a);
$dtEnd = \DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i',$b);

while($dtStart<$dtEnd){
    echo $dtStart->format('H:i') . PHP_EOL;
    $dtStart->modify('+ 1 Hour');
}
```